# FP: Trees - map, fold, each. How?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, functional-programming, category-theory

I have a [working OOP code](https://github.com/Izhaki/gefri/blob/master/src/view/output/dom/canvas/Renderer.ts#L40) that recursively renders a composition of graphical elements to a canvas. There's quite a bit to dislike about it and I'm trying to see what a functional version will look like.

Sure, one can write a specialised recursive pure function, but as the framework involves similar algorithms, I'd like to:

- Harness the power of function **composition**.
- See how FP - and its **data piping** paradigm (transforming data through pure functions) - lands itself to more complex structures than lists (trees/graphs) and less trivial algorithms (than say, finding all odd number by sequentially iterating the list).

Inspired by [Lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/), I've started coding and got this far:

```
LazyTree.from( drawing )
    .keepNodes( visible )
    .keepChildrenOf( nonClipping )
    .traverse( log );
```

But as for **map** and **fold** - I have many unanswered questions.

## Goal

Here's a simplified version of the problem I'm trying to solve:

### Data

A composition (hierarchy) of **rectangles**. The bounds of each are in **relative coordinates** (to its parent):

```
const drawing = {
    name: 'Face',
    bounds: { x: 10, y: 10, w: 100, h: 100 },
    children: [{
        name: 'Left eye',
        bounds: { x: 10, y: 10, w: 20, h: 20 }, // Abs: (20, 20, 20, 20)
        children: [{
            name: 'Left pupil',
            bounds: { x: 5, y: 5, w: 10, h: 10 } // Abs: (25, 25, 10, 10)
        }]
    },{
        name: 'Right eye',
        bounds: { x: 70, y: 10, w: 20, h: 20 }, // Abs: (80, 20, 20, 20)
        children: [{
            name: 'Right pupil',
            bounds: { x: 5, y: 5, w: 10, h: 10 } // Abs: (85, 25, 10, 10)
        }]
    }]
};
```

### Task - getAbsoluteBounds

The task is to convert this composition to one that has absolute coordinates (as shown in the comments).

## Issues and thoughts

### Fold?

The absolute coordinates of a child is its relative coordinates transposed by its parent absolute coordinates. So a **fold** with its accumulator are candidates to do this.

But fold is associated with **catamorphism** and verbs like *combine*, and typically returns a single value.

The transformation in question takes a tree and returns an identical structure but with different values - so it sounds more like a **map**, but one that needs an **accumulator**.

As far as the accumulator goes, it is worth noting that all the children of a specific node should get the same accumulator. For the data above, both `Left eye` and `Right eye` should get the same absolute coordinates of `Face` (as opposed to the `Right eye` getting the returned accumulator of `Left eye` in depth-first-traversal).

Another thing I'm not clear about is who should be in charge of constructing the output tree. Should it be the high-order functions (fold, map, or whatever), or should it be the aggregator?

### Stop conditions

Related the the previous section, consider all rectangles to clip their children, and the following composition:

```
const drawing = {
    name: 'Parent',
    bounds: { x: 10, y: 10, w: 10, h: 10 },
    children: [{
        name: 'Child',
        bounds: { x: 1000000, y: 1000000, w: 10, h: 10 }, 
        children: [{
            name: 'Grandchild',
            bounds: { x: 5, y: 5, w: 5, h: 5 }
        }]
    }]
};
```

The `Child` bounds are out-of-bound with relation to its parent (`Parent`), so branch traversal should stop when traversing to `Child` (no point traversing to `Grandchild`).

The question is: How can this be implemented with a fold function? One solution is to stop branch traversal when the accumulator returns an agreed valued (say `undefined`). But this is somewhat a departure from the fold API for lists.

### Pre and post visit

The rendering algorithm involves:

```
fill( shape );
renderChildren( shape );
stroke( shape );
```

I wonder how this can be achieved with something like `traverse()` or `each()`. Should these take 2 callbacks (pre, post)?

### Traversal strategies

Tree traversal may be:

- **Depth** or **Breadth** first.
- **Top-down** or **Bottom-up** (for the latter, [see a specialised example  for transforming an AST](https://github.com/Sleepyowl/oriju/blob/master/src/Tree.ts#L55), using reduce).

With lists, we have functions like `reverse()`. Lazy.js allows [adding a custom iterator](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/docs/#Sequence) that can then be chained.

So it seems the the FP way to handle traversal strategy is a transforming function. Is there anything else to it?

## Summary

I've touched upon a few of the challenges in implementing a rendering algorithm for a tree structure using the data piping model.

I question if any other FP approaches would be more appropriate here? And perhaps the data piping model is not fit for these sort of problems. Or perhaps, I should simply forget the APIs one sees in FP libraries (that deal nearly exclusively lists) and create one that is appropriate for the task at hand (eg, having a map function that also involves an accumulator).

I couldn't find any FP library dedicated for trees, and information out there is typically limited to very simple problems.

So hopefully, someone would reply with something along the lines of 'this is how it should be done'.

Comment: `map` with accumulator is known as `scan`. However, you don't want one that traverses from left to right (or reverse), but one that accumulates top-down. And including a stop condition makes it even more specialised. Yes, you can write such a thing, but it's nothing usual that can be composed from the standard traversal functions.

Comment: That's @Bergi, that's already helpful. Kind of suggests that while FP has solid treatment for lists, it lacks when it comes to trees. But again, perhaps the approach suggested is flawed.

Comment: Nah, FP principles still apply. It might however be that the library you are using does only handle lists and lacks trees.

Comment: @Bergi. Sorry  - I meant exactly what you have said. Don't quite see how FP or Category Theory can't handle trees - I just that in terms of implementation this hasn't seen much work going into it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood the details you might do as follows.

It will proceed traversing those items remaining within the parent's boundaries, converting their coordinates to absolute and rendering them just afterwards. However if the child's boundaries overlaps the parent's boundaries the child and it's descendants are skipped. No conversion to absolute coordinates and rendering are done for those.

```js
function render(bounds){
  console.log("Rendered:", bounds);
}

function relToAbs(o, b = {x: 0, y:0, w:Infinity, h:Infinity}, go = true){
  go = o.bounds.x < b.w && o.bounds.y < b.h ? (o.bounds.x += b.x, o.bounds.y += b.y, render(o.bounds), go) : !go;
  o.children && go && (o.children = o.children.map(p => relToAbs(p,o.bounds,go)));
  return o;
}

var drawing = {    name: 'Face',
                 bounds: { x: 10, y: 10, w: 100, h: 100 },
               children: [{    name: 'Left eye',
                             bounds: { x: 200, y: 10, w: 20, h: 20 },          // Abs: (20, 20, 20, 20)
                           children: [{    name: 'Left pupil',
                                         bounds: { x: 5, y: 5, w: 10, h: 10 } // Abs: (25, 25, 10, 10)
                                      }]
                          },
                          {    name: 'Right eye',
                             bounds: { x: 70, y: 10, w: 20, h: 20 },          // Abs: (80, 20, 20, 20)
                           children: [{    name: 'Right pupil',
                                         bounds: { x: 5, y: 5, w: 10, h: 10 } // Abs: (85, 25, 10, 10)
                                      }]
                          }]
              };
console.log(JSON.stringify(relToAbs(drawing),null,2));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But other than using `map` this is a specialised function. I'm after something that is more generic and flexible - the framework involves quite a few traversals - some are render, others damage, some accumulate the clipping region, other don't, some accumulate transformations to a single matrix, others to two separate matrices. I don't want to define a new function for each of these, and yes - I could just inject the variations into the master functions, but what I'm really after is composing functions - just like lists are treated.